# Parseerror in Less: Unrecognized input

Tags: css, less

I have a code in Less and I can't run it. Shows Unrecognized input error.

I think this is the problem

```
@divnum: 20;

.rainbow(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
    .rainbow((@counter - 1));
    // Mixin is called within itself, creating the loop, but will only work  while @counter > 0

@clr: @counter * 360/@divnum;
@top:  cos((@counter * 360/@divnum)deg) * 400px;
@left: sin((@counter * 360/@divnum)deg) * 400px;

div:nth-child(@{counter}){
    // nth-child is called based on the counter value
    background-color: hsl(@clr, 100%, 50%);
    position:relative;
    top: @top;
    left: @left;
 }
}
```

Can I use `sin` and `cos` in less? or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: `(1+2)deg` <- this is not valid numeric value. You don't add units to numbers like this in Less (For more details see [#3118](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3118)) And for proper methods see for example https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1375#issuecomment-171446510.

Comment: In short: use `cos(@counter * 360deg / @divnum)` instead.